# If is_archive(), insert code?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to add some code only on the Archive pages. So far, I dropped this into my functions file, but nothing is showing up. Is there something I overlooked?

```
if ( is_archive() ) {
    if (!dynamic_sidebar('categories')) :
        _e('', 'bunyad');
    endif;
}
```

Comment: Yes, you should make this kind of change in a custom page template. Alternatively, use an action hook to add additional functionality in *functions.php*

Comment: @mevius Can you explain how I would go about using an action hook to add additional functionality? I'm using a theme with some restrictions and can't change the necessary page templates.

Comment: wp has a load pattern, at the plugin stage any output will be before the head and a lot of db data will not be loaded yet. hooks/filters all you to run your function at a later stage in the load pattern google all this there is too much to explain and not enough data in your q to be specific but personally i would do as @rnevius has suggested, you can use a child theme or the filter template redirect to achieve this.